# how to reduce mysql select time in phpmyadmin (show end of large table)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a relatively large table in mysql (1M rows), it is indexed so i have no issues with normal operations in my application.
But when I use phpmyadmin and I want to see the end of the table it take 40 seconds to complete because phpmyadmin does:

```
  SELECT * FROM  `table` LIMIT 1116930 , 30
```

Which is not indexed.

Is there a way to see the end of the table using indexed select query?
Preferably using phpmyadmin UI, but if not, is there an indexed mysql query that will show just the last 30 items from the table?

The table has a primary key 'id'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the table in descending order and select the top 30.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30
```

They'll be in descending order, obviously. If that's a problem you can reorder them.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30) AS last30 ORDER BY id
```